# show ipad keyboard when entering text into a series of input fields?

Tags: html, ipad, keyboard

I have a website with a form to capture a phone number.  The designer decided to make the phone number field a series of 10 input fields, each field allowing a maximum of 1 digit.

It is very frustrating to type in my phone number via an ipad.  This is the process for entering a phone number:

1. touch the field for digit 1
2. alpha keyboard comes up
3. toggle to numeric keyboard
4. press a digit
5. keyboard disappears

Repeat steps 1 to 5 for remaining digits 2 to 10.

How do I force the keyboard to always be visible and in numeric mode?  Then onkeyup on each digit field, to automatically focus on the next digit field?

I do not have the option of re-designing this interface.

**Temporary solution**
I'm going to create 1 text input field for all 10 digits, but make border and background transparent.  Then I'm going to use a background image to display 10 separate fields.  But I still don't know how to force the ipad keyboard to go into numeric mode by default.

Comment: Ever come up with a better solution?  This is pretty much a show stopper for me, where I need certain keystrokes in one text field to give focus to another text field, but the ipad on-screen keyboard won't stop disappearing whenever the focus changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use an html5 doctype and `<input type="number" />` [ref](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.number.html) to make tablets and smart phones display a numeric keyboard automatically.

Comment: i used my temporary solution in combination with your answer